# Star employee wants to relocate

Tags: telecommute

Currently, one of my most trusted employees is looking to relocate to be closer with his family, since they do not want to take the plunge and move here. I do not want to risk losing him as he is a valuable asset to our company. Beyond working remotely are there any other solutions anyone can think of? He has expressed making the move work, but because we are in the consulting business, not being on-site at the client could be problematic. Curious if anyone has had experience in this.

Comment: That's really a discussion that you'd need to have with the employee and with knowledge of what your client(s) need.  Some may be perfectly happy with a remote developer as long as you have someone on site.  Some may want the developer to fly in once a month or every few weeks.  Some won't be set up for remote work but will be happy to pay to fly in every week.  Some of these options may not be acceptable to your employee or practical depending on where he or she is moving to and where the client does business.

Comment: You'll have to determine, with a lot of detail, **what** makes this guy a star, and if it can be done remotely.  If they excel at face-to-face meetings and building client confidence, he can't really do that remotely.  This gives you an idea of what to prioritize and determine what kind of output are expected once he is working remote, and whether it is feasible.

Comment: Based on what you say, you can offer him what my father-in-law does. His office is in X, but he lives 4hours away. He's a consultant as well, and what they did in the company was to expand to where he lives too, and his consultancy is done directly less than an hour away from his home. This increases the area of clients to where you are. If he's so good at his job, I bet both will benefit from this.

Comment: Why is this closed? It's nothing to do with company-specific regulations.

Answer (score 6):

Staff come and staff go is my experience. If remote working is out of the question, then I'd train a replacement depending on how far he is moving. If it's just half an hour added to the commute it's probably ok.

My experience is that a 'star' worker in a remote location will pretty soon end up working locally. There is just too many advantages to him/her in doing so, and family pressure also makes a big difference. I was in a long commute situation myself which didn't last long, it was fine with me, but it wasn't fine with the wife. I ended taking a less well paying job that was closer.

It may be worth looking at retaining him as a consultant though. I have that relationship in the neighbouring country where I do some work remotely, and they fly me in for special stuff.

Comment: That's your experience when the employee continues commuting insanely long distances but would you make the same call for someone working remotely? That has its own disadvantages but seems more sustainable.

Comment: @Lilienthal OP already said remote is out of the question, you're correct, remote work is sustainable, just not an option according to the question.

Comment: Ah you're right, +1.